# InvocationTagetException in android?

Tags: android, onclick, invocationtargetexception

I am getting the following exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.vfc.register.RegUserDetailActivity.onNxt(RegUserDetailActivity.java:179)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
```

When i am running my app on android version 2.2.1 getting the above exceptions.

```
    public void onNxt(View v) {
    Log.e("Name", name.getText().toString());}
```

I am just trying to get the entered text in edit text.

What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: Show caller code of this method onNxt..

Comment: I have set onClick="OnNxt" in the button in xml

Comment: `OnNxt !=onNxt` so use `onClick="onNxt"` in xml for setting method for onClick

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i had already done that

Comment: error in xml file,i am sure